# What is the difference between using and not using `New` keyword to define an array?

Tags: java

Look at this two simple program :

Program 1:

```
public class GenArray extends Applet {
    byte[] myArray  ={ (byte) 'M', (byte) 'o', (byte) 'd', (byte) 'e',
            (byte) '1' };
}
```

Program 2:

```
public class GenArray extends Applet {
    byte[] myArray = new byte[5];
    {
        myArray[0]  =(byte) 'M';
        myArray[1]  =(byte) 'o';
        myArray[2]  =(byte) 'd';
        myArray[3]  =(byte) 'e';
        myArray[4]  =(byte) '1';
    }
}
```

I want to know if is there any difference between `MyArray` in the last line of Program-1 and `MyArray` in the last line of Program-2? (Any difference!)

Comment: AFAIK, these both compile to the exact same bytecode.

Comment: @immibis - The byte code is the same. Both call `newarray` but in the first method of creating array is possible only during *initialization*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second program, the `{ ... }` are not array delimiters, they are block delimetes; in this case they are used to give a so-called initializer block, which is executed when a new instance of your class is instantiated.

The "correct" way to create an initialized array is:

```
new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

This can be used always, both when the reference is initialized and when an existing reference is used or when the array is passed to a method:

```
byte[] myArray = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };    // OK
myArray = new byte[] { 4, 5, 6 };           // OK
anObject.someMethod(new byte[] { 7, 8, 9}); // OK
```

However, the first variant is very common and therefore Java allows you to leave the `new byte[]` part out *in that particular case*:

```
byte[] myArray = { 1, 2, 3 };    // OK
myArray = { 4, 5, 6 };           // Does not compile
anObject.someMethod({ 7, 8, 9}); // Does not compile
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a *big* difference. The former can be used only during *initialization* of an array. *Code compilation* will fail if you try to initialize an already defined / declared array with an array constant expression like `{1,2,3}` The latter can be used any-time. The byte-code is same in both cases.

Comment: but i can do `arr = new int[15];`

Comment: @Prashant - Yes. you can because that does not create an array constant.

Comment: This will not change the array object that is created i.e. {1,2,3}, it just change the reference point of  arr

Comment: I wouldn't say that "creates" anything different. The former *syntax* can't be used outside a declaration, but there's nothing different about the objects.

Comment: This answer is actually not true. Both the created array and the reference can be modified when we use the new-less version to create an array. Try to replace the "compile time error" by `arr[0] = 4`.

Comment: @AshishSingh- Edited my answer to make it clearer

Comment: @immibis - Edited my answer to make it clearer

Comment: @Hoopje - Edited my answer to amke it clearer. Yes `arr[0]=4` will work because you are working on the same array.

Comment: @TheLostMind It's still not quite right. Your new answer seems to imply that `int[] a; a = {1, 2, 3};` might compile.

Comment: @pbabcdefp - Changed it to *Code compilation will fail if you try to initialize an already defined / declared array with an array constant expression like {1,2,3}*. Is it fine now?

Comment: @TheLostMind I think it's ok now. If you can find an explanation for *why* you can't write `int[] a; a = {1, 2, 3};` I'll upvote.

Comment: @pbabcdefp - I am looking at the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6), I am not able to find anything related to this query :P